# What does mean "int(i)=1;"?

Tags: c++, c, initialization

I am new to C++, I see following syntax in c++ to initialize variable.

```
int(i)=1;
```

Then, I have compiled in G++ compiler and compiler did not give any error or warning.

So, **What does mean `int(i)=1;` in C and C++?**

Also, I have tested in C, I thought, the C compiler give an error but it's also working fine.

Comment: why do you add the [tag:c] tag? C and C++ are very different languages

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc Because it is also working fine in C.

Comment: @Mahendra Nonetheless, something working in both languages *could* have very different behaviour and reasons. In this case, it's fine, but keep in mind that they are really different.

Comment: Why did you expect an lvalue error? i is an lvalue.

Comment: @Mahendra This is a very different code. i is an lvalue, foo() is not. And the crucial differences are not the parenthesis (well, sort of. They are the reason for the function call). Please look up what lvalues are.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's basically a strange way to write

```
int i = 1;
```

Nothing to worry about.

Sometimes, parenthesis around the variable name are necessary in defintions (eg. pointer to functions), and there is no reason to prohibit them for other cases, so it's allowed without any deeper reason.
<sub>Maythe the author didn't like spaces (such people exist).</sub>

Comment: `(such people exist)` The word you're looking for is "code golfers".

Comment: FWiW, `int i=1` is shorter than `int(i)=1`

Comment: @SilvioMayolo I was looking more for something offensive that I didn't want to spell out ... code golf is fine, but not for work etc.